# How do I remove hard-to-remove ink from my hands?

Tags: cleaning, personal-care, stationery, office-supplies

Sometimes I'll be working with stamps, and stamp ink is sticky and hard to remove.
[image: Rubber stamp]

Even after trying lots of soap, body soap, scratching against a table, and sandpaper the ink still remains on my hands for a day. What can I do to get rid of the ink faster?

*Image from WikiPedia*

Comment: Is wearing gloves an option for you? Prevention is always easier than cure.

Comment: @Duncan, not really. I don't always have gloves handy and it's a pain putting them on, taking the off, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on the type of ink, you might try oil-based hand cleaners such as Goop or acitrus-based solvent, or an alcohol-based solvent, such as isopropyl rubbing alcohol. Though it's **very** hard on the hands and can damage clothing, dilute bleach works for ink-jet stains.

Comment: Second for the automotive hand cleaner.  Haven't tried bleach, though.

Comment: Spilled a printer ink cartridge all over my hands. Same deal, scrubbing with regular products had no result - hands black as pitch and humiliatingly obvious. Did some googling and tried turps, nail polish remover and window cleaner all with no results. Tried diluted bleach, came off in 3 seconds.

Comment: Exactly! it is hard on the skin, though, so I'm more careful to use plastic gloves, now.

Answer (score 5):

You can try using some removing it using certain alcoholic products such as alcohol wipes, nail polish remover, paint thinner. However stronger product such as the pain thinner is not as recommended. Nail polish remover or the alcohol wipes are the best choice though if you have.

Answer (score 2):

I tried all the suggestions but I did not have any luck.

I looked at the toothpaste and thought why not. It was minty crest.
I don't know it that makes a difference.

Put it on the ink, got my nail brush all the ink came off. 
If you don't have a nail brush use a toothbrush.

Good luck.

Comment: Probably the baking soda in the toothpaste is what worked, so look for non-gel toothpastes.

Answer (score 1):

***This might work:***

- Try hairspray. This is said to leave stickiness, but it works.
- Any alcohol based products, even hand disinfectant.  Finishing with a soap rinse works to.
- Dishsoap. This works pretty good, but the thick ones meant for extra cleaning.
- Using nail polish remover works, but make sure to wash your hands afterward really good.

---

**Additional Info**

- Mixing soaps you use with salt or baking soda to make a exfoliant like scrub works.
- Also, trying baby oil may work.

Answer (score 1):

A product called [Amodex](http://amodexink.com/) is a favorite among fountain pen users and it works on a variety of inks. It was invented in the 1950s by a printer and was specifically designed for safe use on skin (its base is lanolin).

[image: amodex ink and stain remover]

For use on fabrics, though, one of the Carbona "[Stain Devil](http://carbona.com/products/staindevils/stain-devils-number-3/)"  spot treatments may be cheaper.  There are nine different formulations and the directions differ subtly, so sure to read carefully.
Stain Devil #3 is the one optimized for inks.

[image: Carbona "Stain Devil" #3]

Answer (score 0):

A Mr. Clean Magic Eraser (dampened with water) works very well, and isn't hard on the skin.

[image: Mr. Clean Magic Eraser]